# how to skip missing dates when looping through a list of dates with do until

Tags: excel, vba, date

I have a production plan that lists models to be produced (column A), production quantity (column B) and production dates (column C). Based on these I calculate ETA dates (column D) for semi-knockdown units (column E) that will be turned into finished models. Each day a varying number of different models are produced, but as long as the original production date is the same, the ETA date (and eventually the PO number) for all semi-knockdowns needed on that particular day will also be the same.

As a next step I want to automatically attach a running PO number (counter in cell J1) to each order for semi-knockdown units - same production date, same PO number. Once the production date changes, the PO number counter is updated +1.

Upon execution my code first checks for the first fresh line in column G, and then asks how many POs to create. Everything works, except for the fact that weekend-/holiday-/ etc dates, which are not listed in the production plan, also update the running PO. In addition, for each missing production date one of the PO cycles is unnecessarily "lost".

The problem seems to be that PO and active date are both updated at the end of my loop, regardless of the date actually being listed.

I tried to fix this by adding a second condition to the IF clause, after adding missing dates and a qualifier ("no prod") to the original production plan, but the code would only run until the first no prod -day. I would also prefer not to add missing dates to the production plan, as it adds another preliminary step to the process.

Another solution might be to only add working days to the initial date when cycles are initially set. That would make sure that no cycles are lost on non-existent dates, but I think the PO counter would still update for missing dates as well.

```
Sub create_PO_021()
'adds the running PO number
'running count of purchase orders
Dim PO As Integer
PO = Range("J1").Value

'counts total used lines based on SKU#
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'searches for first open cell in PO column
Dim rw As Integer
rw = Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

'define first production date for which to create a PO
Dim firstDate As Date
'firstDate = Application.InputBox("On what production date do you want to start:", "Enter date")
firstDate = Cells(rw, 3).Value
MsgBox "Starting at production date" & " " & (firstDate)

'define how many POs you want to create
'count from start date to first gap (week-end or similar)
Dim POcycles As Integer
POcycles = Application.InputBox("How many orders do you want to do?", "Enter number")

'calculate last production date for which to create a PO
Dim lastDate As Date
lastDate = firstDate + POcycles

Dim activeDate As Date
activeDate = firstDate

Do Until activeDate = lastDate
        For a = 1 To lastRow
            If Cells(rw, 3).Value = activeDate Then
                Cells(rw, 7).Value = PO + 1
                Cells(1, 10).Value = PO + 1
                rw = rw + 1
            End If
        Next a
   PO = PO + 1
   activeDate = activeDate + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

The present result for initial PO = 100, and 5 POs to create:
[wrong result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFOqd.png)

The desired result with the same parameters:
[desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEG9I.png)